# Using hydrological equations or DEM map to calculate area inundated for 1m sea level rise scenario?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, sea-level-rise

I want to know how I can calculate the area inundated for a 1m sea level rise (SLR) scenario in ArcGIS Desktop and also the procedure of creating 1m SLR for a particular area.

Do I need to use hydrological equations to get area inundated or by directly from DEM map I can get it?

Comment: Have you [searched](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=flooding) this forum? Typing flooding into the search box returned many similar questions and replies. You may find an answer already here?